# Getting an "undefined method `permit' for "create"" error when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to create an "Action" I get this error.

My Actions controller:

```
class ActionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @match_set = MatchSet.find(params[:match_set_id])
    @fixture = @match_set.fixture
    @teams = Team.where("id = " + @fixture.home_team_id.to_s + " OR id = " + @fixture.away_team_id.to_s)
    @players = Player.where("team_id = " + @teams.ids.first.to_s + " OR id = " + @teams.ids.last.to_s)
    @action = @match_set.actions.new
  end

  def create
    @match_set = MatchSet.find(params[:match_set_id])
    @action = @match_set.actions.new(action_params)

    if @action.save
      redirect_to match_set(@match_set)
    else
      render "actions/new"
    end
  end

  private
    def action_params
      params.require(:action).permit(:team_id, :player_id, :position, :action_type, :action_result)
    end
end
```

It is submitted from this form in views/actions/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [@match_set, @action] do  |f| %> 
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<!-- Team -->
<%= f.label :team_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :team_id, @teams,:id, :name, {include_blank: "Select team..."}, {class: "form-control"} %>

<!-- Player -->
<%= f.label :player_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :player_id, @players,:id, :last_name, {include_blank: "Select player..."}, {class: "form-control"} %>

<!-- Position -->
<%= f.label :position %>
<%= f.select :position, options_for_select(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']), {include_blank: "Select position on court..."}, class: "form-control" %>

<!-- Action Type -->
<%= f.label :action_type %>
<%= f.select :action_type, options_for_select(['Attack', 'Block', 'Pass', 'Set']), {include_blank: "Select action_type..."}, class: "form-control" %>

<!-- Action Result -->
<%= f.label :action_result %>
<%= f.select :action_result, options_for_select(['Score', 'Block', 'Pass', 'Set']), {include_blank: "Select action_type..."}, class: "form-control" %>

<!-- Submit Button -->
<%= f.submit "Add Action", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Also the relevant routes:

```
resources :fixtures, shallow: true do
    resources :match_sets, shallow: true do
      resources :actions
    end
  end
```

I'm getting an error on this line in the controller:

```
params.require(:action).permit(:team_id,:player_id,
:position,:action_type,:action_result)
```

I have also noticed that my parameters seem to be disappearing but again have no clue as to the cause.

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BqbEOfL7hEA8XSMXDvMW2qQ2uR74Egp5
jJvtQlsuyV2TikZJ+6hTIEMH05gy8TM6r3ZglFDRUFBl7ScZD1czCQ==", 
"commit"=>"Add Action", "match_set_id"=>"15"}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` is a reserved word in rails. You will need to change your model name.

Rails provides a few params on each request such as:

```
params[:controller] # maps to your controller name
params[:action]     # maps to an action with your controllers
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html

Comment: I had another issue with reserved words but was given a warning when trying to create the model, which I changed. ("set" changed to "match_set")

Nothing mentioned about unpermitted parameters as far as I can see.

Comment: I looked into the word 'action' a bit more. You should not use `action` in your controllers or models, I would advise to change the model name if possible.